# Deep Filter Of Object Properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm looking for a method that would be able to filter an object's properties based on some sort of data format.  Say I have an object like this:

```
var data = {
  name : {
    first : "Sam",
    last : "Wise",
    invalid : "Not A Valid Property"
  },
  address : "210 Test St.",
  city : "Springfield",
  state : "CA",
  zip : "65565",
  invalid_key1: "Something invalid",
  invalid_key2: "Another invalid one"
}
```

Ideally I'd like to create a method that deep-inspects each property to only allow keys that are present in the filtering object.  I've got a version that works for shallow objects, however I've not came up with a clever way of doing this for sub-objects / arrays.

```
var controlObject = {
  'name' : {
    first : true,
    last : true
  },
  'address' : true,
  'city' : true,
  'state' : true,
  'zip' : true
};

filterObj(data, controlObject);
// Would return:
// {
//   name : {
//     first : "Sam",
//     last : "Wise"
//   },
//   address : "210 Test St.",
//   city : "Springfield",
//   state : "CA",
//   zip : "65565"
// }
```

Here is my current version, which only checks one level deep.

```
_.mixin({
    filterObj : function(data, control) {
    // First set some defaults.
    var _data = data || {};
    var _control = control || {};

    // Create arguments to be passed to _.pick()
    var controlKeys = Object.keys(_control);
    var args = [_data].concat(controlKeys);

    // Finally use _.pick() to filter object properties.
    return _.pick.apply(_, args);
  }
});
```

I've tried to do some finagling to get it to check deeper level objects, however it doesn't seem to be doing it correctly.

```
_.mixin({ 
  filterObj : function(data, control) {
    // First set some defaults.
    var _data = data || {};
    var _control = control || {};

    // Create arguments to be passed to _.pick()
    var controlKeys = Object.keys(_control);
    var args = [_data].concat(controlKeys);

    // Finally use _.pick() to filter object properties.
    var results = _.pick.apply(_, args);

    var moreKeys = Object.keys(_control).filter(function(key) {
      return ( _data[key] == "object" || _data[key] == "array" ) ? true : false
    });

    if( moreKeys.length ) {
      _.each(moreKeys, function(key) {
        results[key] = _.filterObj(_data[key], _control[key]);
      });
      return results;
    } else {
      return results;
    }
  }
});
```

Currently this is set up as an Underscore mixin, though I'm not married to the concept (just makes it easier to use throughout my application).

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is two years old but I had a similar requirement as you did. Other than you I don't have Lodash / Underscore at hand so I came up with a pure JavaScript solution:

```js
function filterObj(data, control) {
  var controlKeys = Object.keys(control),
    results = controlKeys.reduce(function(v, key) {
      if (control[key] === true && data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        v[key] = data[key];
      }

      return v;
    }, {});

  controlKeys.filter(function(key) {
    return typeof control[key] === 'object' && control[key] !== null && !Array.isArray(control[key]) && typeof data[key] === 'object' && data[key] !== null && !Array.isArray(data[key]);
  }).forEach(function(key) {
    results[key] = filterObj(data[key], control[key]);
  });

  return results;
}

var data = {
  name: {
    first: 'Sam',
    last: 'Wise',
    invalid: 'Not A Valid Property'
  },
  gender: 'm',
  password: 'abc123',
  location: {
    address: '210 Test St.',
    city: 'Springfield',
    state: 'CA',
    zip: '65565'
  },
  invalid_key1: 'Something invalid',
  invalid_key2: 'Another invalid one'
}

var controlObject = {
  name: {
    first: true,
    last: true
  },
  gender: true,
  password: false,
  location: true
};

console.log(filterObj(data, controlObject));
```

Please note the fact that I changed some of the logic of your initial approach:

- An option has to be flagged `true` in order to not being filtered out (strict comparison)
- It is possible to flag an entire (sub-)object in order to include it in the result

Hope this helps someone else as well.

Comment: I know this will go against the SO comment policy, but nice work!  :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

The line

> ```
> return ( _data[key] == "object" || _data[key] == "array" ) ? true : false
> ```

is your problem. You're missing the `typeof` operator, and there is no `"array"` type in js - all Arrays are objects. I don't think your function would work as expected on arrays anyway. Better use

```
return (typeof _data[key] == "object") && (_data[key] !== null) && !_.isArray(_data[key]);
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed the `typeof` statements there, the last attempt was something I whipped together in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok for you to use Lodash+[Deepdash](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep):

```
var filtrate = _.filterDeep(data, function(value, key, parent, ctx) {
  return _.has(controlObject, ctx.path);
});
```

Here is a full [test](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash/blob/3f343442d0ee5bf4374cf226ef93741669b6acfa/test/stackoverflow.js#L457) for your case